# redirecting specific page using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect like `http://example.com/sites-related-to-australia-0.html`.
In this "australia" and "0" are parameters. How can i do this using htaccess?   i'm using php.

Any help greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would likely be something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^sites-related-to-(\w+)-(\d+)\.html$ /somewhere_else.php?place=$1&pos=$2 [L]
```

- `/sites-related-to-` will be the first part of the URL
- The next piece (a block of one or more word characters signified by (\w+) (you can also replace this with a more specific (australia|united kingdom|france))) is captured for later as $1
- The piece after the next hyphen will be captured as a digit (\d) and it will be stored as $2
- Load the page somewhere_else.php with get variables place=$1 and pos = $2 (both defined earlier).
- [L] means that this is the last redirect rule which effects this particular pattern.

Comment: i'm going to try and let you know, Thanks.

Comment: Initially your method didn't worked, then i changed it to, RewriteRule ^sites-related-to-(\w+)-(\d+)\.html somewhere_else.php?place=$1&pos=$2 [L] and it worked. both htaccess and that somewhere_else.php is under public_html folder. What is the difference to your method and mine?

Comment: I just fixed this in the answer, but I accidentally had an extra '/' at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts cwallenpoole, Cheers ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^sites-related-to-(\w+)-(\d+).html/$ sites-related-to.html?country=$1&val=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RedirectMatch sites-related-to-([^-]+)-(\d+)\.html$ http://www.anotherserver.com/something.php?country=$1&id=$2
```

Untested, see [`RedirectMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch).